# Ruby on Rails: Use Flatly Theme for Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Question: I like bootstrap and have it FULLY working in Ruby on Rails; I however found a nice theme from bootswatch.com called Flatly;  I wish to use it in my SASS based application. Where do I put this new bootstrap.min.css file?

1) I have Ruby(2.2.1) on Rails (Rails 4.0+) and I have installed the following gems

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

According to https://bootswatch.com, the Flatly THEME only requires a newly downloaded bootstrap.min.css file. I have tried the FOLLOWING things and failed.

1. Tried to Download the boostrap.min.css file and place it in the app/assets/stylesheets. (failed)
2. I have tried using other Gem's but they are to hard; I couldn't get it to work. In my MOCK up i just copied the new boostrap.min.css file over my prior one and instant profit.
3. I am using application.css.scss with the following

   `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";`
   `@import "bootstrap";`
4. I am using boostrap-sprockets if that makes a difference.

I have a HUNCH that this has something to do with the SCSS pre-compilation file; I just can't figure out where ot change the initial bootstrap file.

Any Suggestions would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone:

1. Remove the @import "bootstrap" from the application.css.scss
2. Put your new min in the app/stylesheets folder for the new theme

Win.